# How to mock a Consumer argument using EasyMock with PowerMock

Tags: powermock, easymock

I have a test scenario where I need to mock a Consumer parameter.

In the following code the `startTracer` is the method to be tested.

```java
class TracerService {

    private TracerController tracerController;

    public void startTracer(String tracerName, Object param1) {
        if (attendStartConditions(tracerName, param1)) {
            executeOnTracerControllerScope(tracerController -> tracerController.startTracer(param1));
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Basically, I want to test if the `tracerController.startTracer(param1)` is receiving the `param1` as argument.

```java
Capture<Object> method1Param1 = newCapture();
tracerController.startTracer(capture(method1Param1));
expectLastCall().once();
...
tracerService.startTracer("TEST", "value1");
assertThat(method1Param1.getValue()).isEqualsTo("value1");
```

How I can configure EasyMock/PowerMock for that `executeOnTracerControllerScope` execute `tracerController.startTracer` without invocating their internal code?

Answer (score 1):

`tracerController` is a mock. So `startTracer` won't be called on it. As defined right now, it will simply do nothing. The code doing what you are asking should be something like that:

```
Capture<Object> method1Param1 = newCapture();
tracerController.startTracer(capture(method1Param1)); // no need for the expect, it's the default
replay(tracerController);
// ...
tracerService.startTracer("TEST", "value1");
assertThat(method1Param1.getValue()).isEqualsTo("value1");
```

Of course, `attendStartConditions` and `executeOnTracerControllerScope` will be called for real.

Following your comment, if you want to mock `executeOnTracerControllerScope`, you will do the code below. However, your lambda won't be called anymore. So you won't be able to validate the param.

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        TracerController tracerController = mock(TracerController.class);
        TracerService service = partialMockBuilder(TracerService.class)
                .withConstructor(tracerController)
                .addMockedMethod("executeOnTracerControllerScope")
                .mock();
        replay(tracerController);

        service.startTracer("tracer", "param");
    }
}

class TracerService {

    private final TracerController tracerController;

    public TracerService(TracerController tracerController) {
        this.tracerController = tracerController;
    }

    public boolean attendStartConditions(String tracerName, Object param1) {
        return true;
    }

    public void executeOnTracerControllerScope(Consumer<TracerController> tracer) {
        tracer.accept(tracerController);
    }

    public void startTracer(String tracerName, Object param1) {
        if (attendStartConditions(tracerName, param1)) {
            executeOnTracerControllerScope(tracerController -> tracerController.startTracer(param1));
        }
    }

}

interface TracerController {
    void startTracer(Object param1);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but besides that, suppose that I wan't to create a partial mock from TracerService (to test the `startTrace` method). In this case, there is some way to mock the method `executeOnTracerControllerScope`?